# Limit with L'hopitals?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{p \to 0}(\alpha_1x_1^{p}+\alpha_2x_2^p)^{1/p}$$

If anybody at all can help me take this limit. The solutions manual I'm using says you can apply l'hopitals rule here but I'm pretty sure you can't.

Been stuck on this for hours, would really appreciate some help.

Comment: what are the variables?

Comment: Well the alphas are just elements of the reals, as are the x's (technically this is a demand function in an economic problem but it's the same thing basically)

Comment: from where do you know that such a limit exists?

Comment: Well the problem is to show that this limit forms another well known demand function in economics. So I'm assuming that this exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,x_1,x_2>0$, otherwise the expression is not well defined.

When the limit involves the variable in the exponent, it's better to compute (if it exists) the limit of the logarithm of the expression. I use “log” to denote the natural logarithm:
$$
\lim_{p \to 0}\log(\alpha_1x_1^{p}+\alpha_2x_2^p)^{1/p}
=
\lim_{p \to 0}\frac{\log(\alpha_1x_1^{p}+\alpha_2x_2^p)}{p}
$$
If $\alpha_1+\alpha_2\ne1$, the limit doesn't exist, because it's $\infty$ from the right and $-\infty$ from the left, so we study it when $\alpha_2=1-\alpha_1$, so it becomes
$$
\lim_{p \to 0}\frac{\log(\alpha_1x_1^{p}+(1-\alpha_1)x_2^p)}{p}
=
\lim_{p\to0}\frac{\alpha_1x_1^p\log x_1+(1-\alpha_1)x_2^p\log x_2}{\alpha_1x_1^{p}+(1-\alpha_1)x_2^p}
$$
which is not indeterminate any more and is equal to
$$
\alpha_1\log x_1+(1-\alpha_1)\log x_2=
\log(x_1^{\alpha_1}x_2^{1-\alpha_1})
$$

Comment: This is perfect! This is exactly the answer I need to get to. Thank you so much I've been stuck on this for hours!